# Not able to understand this graph for rational function .

Tags: functions

[image]

I am not getting why there are 3 lines drawn in that way .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x=2$ or $x = -2$ you get $\frac {x^2-3x-2}{x^2 - 4}$ will have $x^2 - 4 = (\pm 2)^2 -4 = 0$ and the whole thing is undefined and can not be plotted.  For values where $x$ is close to $0$ then $x^2 - 4$ will be very small in magnitude and so $\frac 1{x^2- 4}$ will be very large in magnitude and the function will stretch to very large positive or negative values and as $x\to 0$ the $|\frac {x^2-3x-2}{x^2 - 4}| \to \infty$.  The vertical lines $x =2$ and $x=-2$ are the vertical asymptotes and as $x$ is very close to $\pm 2$ the graph will get very close to those vertical lines.

$y = 1$ is the horizontal asymptote.  As $x$ gets very very large then the the proportional difference between the numerator and the denominate will get insignificant and the value of $\frac {x^2 - 3x-2}{x^2 -4}$ will get closer and closer to $1$. (for example if $x=10$ you have $\frac {x^2-3x-2}{x^2-4} =\frac {100-30 -2}{100 -4} = \frac {68}{96}$ but and $x =100$ you have $\frac {x^2-3x -2}{x^2 - 4}=\frac {10000-300 -2}{10000 - 2}=\frac {9698}{9992}$.)

More formally $\frac {x^2 -3x -2}{x^2 - 4} = \frac {x^2 -4 -3x +2}{x^2 -4}=1 -\frac {3x-2}{x^2-4}$ and as $x \to \pm \infty$ we have $\frac {3x-2}{x^2 -4} \to 0$.

so the graph gets close to $y=1$ for large positive and negative values of $x$.

This is the nature of assymptotes.  It's pretty important you understand them.  Keep studying.

Answer (score -1):

As the final sentence above "Example 2" says, those are the asymptotes of the function, lines which the graph approaches as $x$ approaches $\pm\infty$, or as $x\to\pm2$ (in which case $y$ approaches $\pm\infty$).

Comment: Actually as $y$ approaches $2$ or $-2$.  Not $\infty$.

Comment: That's $x$ approaching those values. I've edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: Still incorrect. The *vertical* lines (up and down) are for when $x$ approaches $\pm 2$ then $y$ approaches $\pm \infty$.  Whereas the *horizontal* line (side to side) are for when $x$ approaches $\pm \infty$ then $y$ approaches $1$.

Comment: You have misread my edit. All three lines are asymptotes. The horizontal one is as $x\to\pm\infty$ and the vertical ones are as $x\to\pm2$ in which case $y\to\pm\infty$. I omitted the limit of $y$ as $x\to\pm\infty$, but my statement is correct.

Comment: "You have misread my edit."  That's true.  But that's because your edit is ambiguous and poorly written.  It *very* much sounds you are so that as $x$ approaches $\pm \infty$ or $\pm 2$ then in those four cases $y$ approaches $\pm \infty$.  You should make the clearer.

Comment: The key aspect of the concept of an asymptote is that some variable is approaching $\pm\infty$. I believe that my original phrasing made that more clear than the unnecessarily convoluted approach which you seem to prefer.